# Toggle of mobile menu not working properly

Tags: javascript, css

I am building a responsive navigation bar. The toggling of hide/show is working for mobile (max-width:699px) but when i increase the screen width, the links of navbar either is hidden or shows in block. I want whenever I increase the screen width, the nav should display in flex rather inheriting parent properties. Can anyone help me please.

```js
var span = document.querySelector("span");
var second = document.querySelector(".second");

span.addEventListener('click', function() {

  if (second.style.display === "none") {
    second.style.display = "flex";
  } else {
    second.style.display = "none";
  }
});
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

nav {
  margin: auto;
  height: 500px;
}

nav ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
}

nav a {
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 10px;
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
}

nav span {
  display: block;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  position: absolute;
  padding: 10px;
}

.first a {
  text-align: left;
}

.first {
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}

.second {
  display: none;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 700px) {
  nav {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
  }
  nav ul {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between
  }
  nav span {
    display: none;
  }
  .second {
    display: flex;
  }
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul class="first">
    <li><a href="#">Heading</a></li>
  </ul>
  <ul class="second">
    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
  </ul>
  <span>
            <i class="fas fa-bars"></i>
        </span>
</nav>
```

Comment: It is displaying in flex I think. How do you want it to behave?

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve the behavior that you want by toggling a class that has the necessary styles attached to it. When you put the styles directly on the element those styles will be prioritized higher than the class based styling you have.

Add styling

```
.flex { display: flex; }
```

And use this Javascript

```
var span = document.querySelector("span");
var second = document.querySelector(".second");
span.addEventListener('click', function() {
  second.classList.toggle("flex")
});
```

Example codepen:
https://codepen.io/danba340/pen/ZEOjozz

Comment: Thanks dude now its working pretty fine as expected

Comment: Happy to hear :)